# Make Input Field Output Links

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So, I added an input field to one of my post types.

What I'm trying to do is put a link (google.com, facebook.com, any link) into this field, and have it output on the front end into a button.

Below is my button. I would like it to go to the link I placed on the input field when I click the button.

```
<a href="" id="btn-book-now" class="btn-custom"><?php  echo __('Purchase Now','Vierra'); ?></a>
```

Here's the code for the metabox:

```
<?php

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cart_meta_box_add' );  
function cart_meta_box_add() {  
    add_meta_box( 'cart-meta-box-id', 'Put cart Here!', 'cart_meta_box_cb', 'Room', 'side', 'high' );  
}  
function cart_meta_box_cb() {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'cart_meta_box_nonce' );
    $value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'cart_key', true);
    $html = '<label>cart: </label><input type="text" name="cart" value="'.$value.'"/>';
    echo $html;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'cart_meta_box_save' );  
function cart_meta_box_save( $post_id ){   
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return; 
    if ( !isset( $_POST['cart_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['cart_meta_box_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) return;
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;  
    if( isset( $_POST['cart'] ) )  
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'cart_key', esc_attr( $_POST['cart'], $allowed ) );
}

?>
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same function used in the admin: [`get_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). Assuming the button is being printed inside the loop `*`:

```
<?php
if( $field = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cart_key', true ) ) {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $field; ?>" id="btn-book-now" class="btn-custom">
        <?php echo __('Purchase Now','Vierra'); ?>
    </a>
    <?php
}
?>
```

*`*` Otherwise, you'd use `$post->ID` instead of `get_the_ID()`.*

Comment: Thank you, especially for adding the extra tidbit.